# jQuery datepicker keeps returning mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a jQuery datepicker defined in my code like this:

```
$fromDate = strtotime($vacancy[0]->vacancy_visibility_start_date);
$fromDate = date('d/m/Y',$fromDate);
$calendarFromArray = array(
    'name' => 'datepicker',
    'id' => 'datepicker',
    'value' => $fromDate
);
```

My JS looks like this:

```
$( "#datepickerfrom" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});
$( "#datepickerto" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});
```

Even though the datepicker appears and works the date remains in `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

Comment: it works, see https://jsfiddle.net/depperm/1Lkvoqes/1/

Comment: @RobScott it does.